# Laravel mix react build code is not working on cpanel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Iam using laravel-mix on laravel 9 for intrigating react into my application its all working on localhoat but when i tried to deploy it in cpanel first if all path is not working correctly even after loading the js file manually the js functionality is not working.

Laravel Mix Config

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

Asset Loading

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

I am deploying it in public-html/laravel and adding htaccess on this folder to redirect to public.

Any solution will really be appreciated